# Проблема с вытаскиванием данных из файла jquery

Tags: jquery

ДД. Хочу сделать поле с автозаполнением в поиске, т.е. человек начинает вбивать слово поиска и автоматически выводится список близких по значению. Использую следующий код:

```
  var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC",
  "C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran",
  "Groovy","Haskell","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP",
  "Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
```

где `availableTags` -  список значений, которые автоматически будут потом подставляться.
Вызываю `<1input type="text" class="search" id="tags">` и все работает на ура. Хотел спросить, как вместо переменной `availableTags` обращался к файлу, в котором будет список всех подходящих слов. С уважением. Жду ответа.

p.s. Новичок в jquery, ногами не пинать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Чтение XML файла с помощью jQuery](http://www.xiper.net/learn/lessons-jquery/ajax/reading-xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

ну тут необязательно юзать xml... более того, если контент статический то идеальное решение - старый добрый txt.
Просто прописываете в txt фйле все необходимые вам слова и на .ready делаете аякс запрос, потом просто разбиваете полученые данные в массив и будет вам счастье :)

Если же контент автокомплита динамичен - то ajax'ом на том же .ready делать запрос только не к статическому txt файлу а уже к php скрипту, тогда вообще идеально было бы юзать JSON.

небольшой пример:

```
function myFunction(data) {
    alert(data); // собственно тут у нас уже строка из файла
        // ну а дальше например строку можно разбить на массив с помощью .split()
        // вообщем это уже на ваше усмотрение :)
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("/public/css/main.css", myFunction);
});
```

Comment: все бы ничего, просто я же говорю я новичок в jquery как это все описать.

Answer (score 0):

На http://api.jquery.com находится отличная документация по jQuery. Конкретно в вашем случае читайте http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, особенно про dataType.